# Detecting if parent page has gallery

Tags: php, functions, gallery

My function to detect is a gallery is on a page has broken and Im not sure why. So in my theme template's attachment page Im calling this function:

```
global $post;

$parent_id = $post->post_parent;

if ( strpos(get_post($parent_id)->post_content,'[gallery ') == false ){
    $navigation_markup = 'no gallery';
}else{ $navigation_markup = 'theres a gallery!' }
```

It USED to work, but last night I noticed that it stopped and I'm not sure why.

if the only (or first) thing in a post/page is `[gallery id="1,2,3,4,5"]` my function fails. However, if I add a space, or any character really it passes and detects the gallery.

So something about `[gallery` being in the very first position returns false.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns 0 (zero index position) when gallery shortcode is at the start of the content which is treated as `false` by the if condition.

Solution is to use Identical operator `===` in condition to check if the return value is a boolean `false`.

Answer (score 1):

With WordPress 3.6 you can use this new function :

```
if( function_exists('has_shortcode') 
    && has_shortcode( get_post($parent_id)->post_content, 'gallery' )  )     {
       //code
    } else {
       //maybe your function as fallback for previous versions of WP
     }
```